# Redirecting output from printf to /dev/tty in awk

Tags: tty, awk

I have a question on awk.

```
#!/usr/bin/nawk -f
{
    if (NF != 4) {
        error("Expected 4 fields");
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
function error ( message ) {
    if (FILENAME != "-") {
        printf("%s: ", FILENAME) > "/dev/tty";
    }
    printf("line # %d, %s, line: %s\n", NR, message, $0) >> "/dev/tty";
}
```

What does `>"/dev/tty"` and `>>"/dev/tty"` do?

It's from https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html under User Defined Functions.

Comment: It's for gawk rather than nawk, but see [5.7 Special Files for Standard Preopened Data Streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Special-FD)

Comment: @steeldriver thx. i guess it is to redirect error message to stderr. the document you gave says it's better to do print "error!" >"/dev/stderr".